# ppp и его маршруты

Tags: linux, сеть, centos, ppp, ipsec

Настроил libreswan (ipsec) + xl2tp в качестве клиента до одного провайдера. Поднимается ikev1 шифрованый канал, через него поднимается ppp тунель и дальше мне приходится прописывать роут через тунельную сеть, что я делаю скриптом

```
    function route_add () {
        ip r a 192.168.10.88 via 172.16.0.1 dev ppp0
    }

    ip r | grep -q "192.168.10.88"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        route_add
        sleep 5
    fi

    /bin/ping -q -c 3 192.168.10.88 >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "d provider" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
        sleep 1
        service xl2tpd restart

        sleep 5
        route_add
    fi
```

Этот скрипт запускается по крону и "чинит" тунель в случае его падения, а такое, к сожалению, иногда случается.

А что делать, если тунелей у меня там будет 100500? Как роуты прокидывать в этом случае? Я не могу гарантировать что одному тунелю будет присвоен всегда ppp0, второму ppp1 и т.д. Может есть способ как-то xl2tp заставить роуты прописывать? Но тогда всё равно вопрос с watchdog'ом остаётся актуален.

Comment: Среди опций pppd есть такая штука — `unit`. Она задаёт номер ppp-интерфейса для данного пира. То есть если передан `unit 20`, то интерфейс будет ppp20. А ещё есть ipparam, который передаётся шестым параметром скрипту /etc/ppp/ip-up. А ещё ему передаётся пятым параметром remote IP. В общем, есть по какому признаку различить, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Способ 1**

создайте файл : `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0010routes`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $@ > /tmp/last-ppp-ip-up-args
env > /tmp/last-ppp-ip-up-env

if [ "$PEERNAME" -eq "username" ] ;
then ;

ip r d 192.168.0.0/24 metric ${metric}
ip r a 192.168.0.0/24 metric ${metric} via $5 dev $1

fi
```

$PEERNAME - логин ppp

$5 - ip пира

$1 - имя девайса

**Способ 2**

Установи `bird`

```
apt install bird
```

в файл /etc/bird/bird.conf добавить

```
protocol static {
        route 192.168.129.0/24 via 192.168.94.36;
}
```

При появлении маршрута до `192.168.94.36` `bird` добавит маршрут сразу.